# How do I pass complex objects in a web service for all clients to consume

Tags: .net, web-services

I need to create a web service in .net that will allow clients to pass complex application information into the service. The service will validate all information and then either enter the info into a DB or return a list of errors to the client so they can correct them and resubmit the application.

The web service will need to be able to be consumed by any client (meaning java, php .net ...)

If I were only working with .net clients I could make my class objects available as public classes to the  client and they would have access to all properties, enums and structures in the object. such as :

```
' Add Personal info and set property
  tempPersonalClass = New IDVerifyWebService.clsPersonal
```

In the example above the clsPersonal class could include multiple properties, enums and even sub classes. The client should be able to instantiate this class and iterate all levels.

My question is in what manner(XML, JSON or some other type) could I pass my class object to the client in order for them to be able to work with it populate it with the values and return it?

Comment: Wouldn't you just need the client code to parse the WSDL file of your web service with whatever tool is available for the specific platforms?

Comment: This is what I am asking. I have developed .net apps that consume web services and webservices in .net that I have consumed but I am not sure of what limitations there are when making this available to other platforms.

Comment: I would think if you have a valid, standards-based WSDL, it should not be a problem.  For java clients, there are several frameworks available to consume web services - CXF, Axis2. Take a look at those.

Comment: Using the app SoapUI I was able to communicate with the webservice and get results based off the WSDL. So this means the complex class objects are defined in the WSDL in XML format by default (Assumption). I did notice 2 things 1)the comments on my class objects in .net did not come through as they all said optional and did not define the type expected 2) the enum types are not included at all.